# How to detect boxing/unboxing in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, boxing

I'm interested in finding all the places in my solution where boxing or unboxing occur. I know that I can use ildasm like this:

```
Ildasm.exe yourcomponent.dll /text | findstr box
```

but I prefer not to look at the MSIL level.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You could probably use Roslyn for this... have you looked into that?

Comment: I think it would be a lot of work to parse the syntax tree in Roslyn to figure this out. You could do it, but honestly ildasm is the cheapest way. Are you concerned about boxing for perf reasons or are you just curious?

Comment: @MichaelBraude, Mainly curiosity. Just wanted to generate a report for my team about all the places

Comment: I see. Thanks. I would suggest a different approach. Rather than find all of the places where you box / unbox, take a perf trace and determine whether garbage collection is impacting the performance of your app. If it is, then you can dive into the pieces of your code that are problematic and fix them. The way to identify those is again, through a trace. Boxing / unboxing may be impacting your perf... and it may not. The only way you'll know for sure if by taking a trace. I think that would be a more useful exercise than what you're trying to do.

Comment: Even though it may not affects the performance, I thought there will be a tool out there which can map all the places in the code with boxing. I guess I was wrong

Answer (score 1):

[Clr Heap Allocation Analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MukulSabharwal.ClrHeapAllocationAnalyzer) is a free Visual Studio add-on that detects many (but not all) forms of boxing and will highlight your source code and provide a tooltip explanation.

You can also use the Visual Studio [Diagnostic Tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/02/15/analyze-cpu-memory-while-debugging/) to analyze memory allocations. This won't reveal boxing directly, but any time you see a value type on the heap you know it's been boxed (for example, you will see that a references to Int32 takes 12 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with FXCOP: (old article with example)

[Link - Three Vital FXCop Rules](https://web.archive.org/web/20040823234309/http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/04/09/Bugslayer/)

Answer (score -2):

This is a perfect use case of #Roslyn The Compiler as a Service that is coming out from Microsoft and Jon Skeet as usual is absolutely right. I am writing a book on Roslyn to show how to do these sort of code analytics using Roslyn and top it off with some eye catching visualization by JavaScript.

Here is the code for finding boxing calls. However scope resolution plays a role. But this example should get you started. Pre-order your copy to get more such at [https://www.amazon.com/Source-Analytics-Roslyn-JavaScript-Visualization/dp/1484219244?ie=UTF8&](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484219244)*Version*=1&*entries*=0

https://gist.github.com/sudipto80/43efdecb878cac17b340cda2c281c3b3